# Zend Framework 2 - How to use an external library

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to add my custom class "Authentication.php" to my project but I don't understand how I have to do it ?

I have read many howto about the external libs but nothing work.

ZendFramework/module/Firewall/Module.php

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/MyNamespace/lib/MyNamespace',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

ZendFramework/vendor/MyNamespace/lib/MyNamespace
                                                  /Authentication.php

```
<?php

class Authentication {

public function test()
{
     die('Works fine');
}


}

?>
```

How I can call my external lib in my controllers.

Thanks you very much !

Comment: if you place your class in module/ModuleName/src/ModuleName/, your class must have 'namespace ModuleName;' instruction to use default autoloader. It will be available calling new \ModuleName\Authentication();

Comment: i think you forget add namespace part in `Authentication.php`

Comment: thanks Mohamad, the problem was the namespace too ! Again, thanks you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I try like this:

1)

```
//module/Application/Module.php
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'Mynamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/Mynamespace',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

2)

```
//vendor/Mynamespace/MyClass.php
namespace Mynamespace;
class MyClass
{
    //...
}
```

3) I use it, for example in my controller:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Mynamespace\MyClass;
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $myclass = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: i did the same as described, but i got error , i have the folder like : aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws , so i write the path in the name space : public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                     'Aws' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of library, just type in your **application.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'Application',
        'YourLibrary' // <-- here
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in composer.json file add the library as below

```
 "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
            "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
            "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
            "twig/twig": ">=1.12.3",

        }
```

Then in your **application.config.php**
 under the modules array

```
'modules' => array(
        'Application',
            'ZendDeveloperTools',
            'ZfcTwig',
            'DoctrineModule',
            'DoctrineORMModule','yourdir',

    ),
```

So do something similar to it.