# How to work with aws-sdk-php in zf2 project?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2, aws-sdk

I actually know that there is a aws-sdk-php module for ZF2 which is named `aws-sdk-php-zf2`, but I have a part using the simple `sdk` and I would like to work with it inside my zf2 controllers without having 2 sdks; one for simple PHP and another for ZF2 scripts. Is there any way to make it work?

Here is the way I work using the aws-sdk in a simle PHP script:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
// Instantiate an S3 client
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret_key',
    )
));
$bucket = 'bucket_name';
$keyname = 'project_name/file.ext';

$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname
)); 
print_r($result);
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to load it as an external library in your zf2 project, please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523127/1386551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once installed via Composer:

1) Put it into the `public/init_autoloader.php` file to set the library available all over the app, this is mine:

```
// Composer autoloading
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
}

$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) { //Support for ZF2_PATH environment variable or git submodule
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { //Support for zf2_path directive value
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}

if ($zf2Path) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

2) Use it in the controller as you wish, in my case the following is a private function inside a controller:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception as S3Exception;
...
private function s3UploadFile($id, $invalidation=false, $file = null, $content = null){
   $response = '';
   //check if the file already exists in S3, if not then build it
   try {
       $s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
                   'key' => $this->config['aws']['key'],
                   'secret' => $this->config['aws']['secret'],
                   'region' => $this->config['aws']['region']
       ));

       if (!$s3Client->doesObjectExist('clients','/' . $id . '/' . $file))
           $s3Client->putObject(array(
               'Bucket' => 'clients',
               'Key' => '/' . $clientId . '/' . $file,
               'Body' => $content,
               'ACL' => 'public-read'
           ));
   } catch (S3Exception $e) {
       $response = 'error';
   }
   return $response;
}
...
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but you didn't mention where to put the new librabry ? beside that the init_autoloader.php is outside public , it's in the same place as public... plz can u clarify it a little bit more ...

Comment: Using Composer, the library should be under /myproyect/vendor/aws. I am assume you use Composer via your "composer.json" file which is located in "/myproyect/composer.json".

Comment: But what i see is that you didn't change anything in the file init_autoloader.php ... i have the same content , also i can't see where did u declare the aws library ( the namespace i think ... )

Comment: Look at the beginning of the file, we are loading the vendor/autoload.php which is the loader for all the libraries installed via Composer.