# how can I use Zend framework 2 with external library in separate directory (not vendor)

Tags: zend-framework, solr, zend-framework2, hbase

I am using zend framwork 2 and I want to use some library like Hbase or Solr in a separate folder outside of my application, how can i do that?

```
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include '../Mylibrary/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

when i copy the folder of my library into vendor folder it work : but i want to use it from another folder oustide off my application .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 - How to use an external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522772/zend-framework-2-how-to-use-an-external-library)

Answer (score 0):

In your `init_autoloader.php`

```
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader->addPsr4('Mylibrary\\', __DIR__ . '/../Mylibrary/');
}
```

Or in your own `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Mylibrary\\": "Mylibrary/"
    }
},
```

Comment: thanks i do it but i have an error in my library ,i want a way to use Hbase connection with zend Framework 2 .Thanks for your Answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use Composer's [`path` repository feature](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path).

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*@dev"
    }
}
```